# xv6 installation in WSL (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: operating-system, ubuntu-20.04, xv6

I have been trying to install xv6 using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
tar xzvf xv6-rev11.tar.gz
cd xv6-public
make
make qemu
```

I get the following error while running `make qemu` command

```
qemu-system-i386 -serial mon:stdio -drive file=fs.img,index=1,media=disk,format=raw -drive file=xv6.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -smp 2 -m 512
make: qemu-system-i386: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:225: qemu] Error 127
```

As suggested at various places, I have un-commented line 54 `QEMU = qemu-system-i386` in the makefile before executing `make qemu`

Please help me fix the error. Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the package containing `qemu-system-i386`.
After a little search on https://packages.ubuntu.com, you can find the right package: [qemu-system-x86](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/qemu-system-x86/filelist).

To install the missing package, type

```
sudo apt install qemu-system-x86
```